# How do I prove the two different definition of group is equivalent?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A group is a monoid $(G, *)$ (i.e. $*$ is associative and has an identity
element $e$) such that for every element $x$ element $G$ there exists an element $y$ element $G$((i.e $\forall x\in G \exists y\in G$)) such that
$xy = yx = e$. Such an element $y$ is called a symmetrical element or an inverse
(element) for $x$.

and the second definition is:
A set with an internal operation $*$ is a group if and only if

$(i)$ is associative,

$(ii)$ given any two elements $x, y$ element of $G$, there exist unique elements $a, b$ element of $G$ such that
$ax = y$ and $xb = y$.

and that the definition of equivalent is that it has to satisfy the following three axioms.
$x R x$,
$x R y$ implies $y R x$
and
$x R y$ implies that if $y R z$ then $x R z$

Comment: An easier way of showing equivalence between the two definitions is to show that if an object is a group under definition 1 then it is a group under definition 2, and also that if it is a group under definition 2 it is a group under definition 1.

Comment: The definition of "equivalent" you looked up applies to a completely different context (the one of "equivalence relation on a set"). Here, it just means that a pair set-binary operation $(G,*)$ satisfies condition $(a)$ if and only if it satisfies condition $(b)$.